# How to show different layouts of wordpress theme of the same wordpress theme in the demo

Tags: wordpress, themes

How can I show different layouts of a wordpress theme such as:

1. Homepage with sidebar
2. Homepage without sidebar
3. Homepage with list layout
4. Homepage with grid layout

These are the options that can be set from Theme Options but there is no URL that I can call on any page.

I want to show my theme demo with these layouts as this designer is doing here in the menu bar: http://solopine.com/redwood/

This is the list layout of the wordpress theme http://solopine.com/redwood/?home_layout=list

but how can I do it with my theme demo.

Is there a wordpress plugin or some coding required? Please answer. Thanks

Comment: You can create page templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you just bought this theme and have problem adjusting it.

Sometimes these demos come pre-built in a theme and sometimes you have to configure them yourself.

When you go to edit the actual homepage check on the right where it says "Template". There is a dropdown which let's you select the template for the page.

On the other hand there also might be "Sidebar" settings there too which lets you control where the sidebar will be placed. I can't tell much without seeing it.

If you need a direct help you can give me acces to take a look at it and then explain better how you can control this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If the theme uses page templates as a way to determine the layout of the page set as the 'Home' page, you can add more pages with different home page layouts by selecting the template in the edit page dialog.  Then just add a list of links to each home page layout on your main home page.

However, if the theme only lets you select a home page layout from the options panel, you may be out of luck without custom coding.